# How do I keep Subtree in sync with repos who use it?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-subtree

I created a subtree called `styles` and I am importing it into `public/styles/` in another repo - and plan to share it with others as well.

I was able to create the subtree and also import the subtree into the other project. My issue is - that I was also able to successfully change the file in the downstream project and push the change. This can potentially cause some big problems when trying to keep all projects that share `styles` in-sync with one another.

What am I doing wrong?